# Formtastic - custom return value for :include_blank option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm using Formtastic (in ActiveAdmin), and I need to display a collection in a select tag for a field handled by the Ancestry gem.
It's working well for the collection, but I also need a blank value in the list for clearing the field.
I've tried :include_blank, but it's returning an empty string, but the validator (I can't change it, it's in the Ancestry gem) rejects it because it want nil.

How I can change the return value of :include_blank in order to return nil instead of an empty string ?

my code:

```
 f.input :ancestry, as: :select, collection: Category.all, :member_value => Proc.new { |c| c.path_ids.join("/") }, include_blank: true
```

"include_blank: true" is optional here, it's doing the same thing with or without it.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you use `f.input :parent_id` instead of `f.input :ancestry`?